# If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have proved :

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

But when it extends $(a,b)$ to $\Bbb{R}$, I don't know how to continue. Would you please give some instructions?

Comment: The identity map $f(x)=x$ on the real line is uniformly continuous but not bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true for the whole real line but it is true for any closed interval. 
It is in fact true for any compact subset of real numbers.